# ODBC Config File for Datastage Connection to SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, unix, odbc, unixodbc, datastage

I have an odbc config file on a sun solaris server, used for IBM datastage.
We need to connect to a sqlserver express edition.
Ip used to connect is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\TARGET
port is 1433,
database is dbname.

Sample of config file is:

```
[T_TEST]
Driver=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded _odbc/lib/VMmsss23.so
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol driver
Database=dbname
LogonID=user
Password=*****
Address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\TARGET,1433
Instance=SQLEXPRESS
QuotedId=No
AnsiNPW=No
```

If I try to connect to sqlserver from datastage, I can't!

If I try to connect to sqlserver from Management Studio, using like server name field value "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\TARGET", I can.

Is the config file correct about your opinion or is there some setting to do on sqlserver?

Sqlserver machine has port 1433 open for connection from datastage server.

All other connections to sqlserver machine go.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Address configuration not right.you should get the sql server IP address only and config the Address only IP address and port.Then,check the odbc configuration is normally worked using the below two ways:

(1)

```
$cd /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded_odbc/example
$./example
Enter the data source name : T_TEST
Enter the user name        :
Enter the password         :
```

(2)

```
$cd $DSHOME/bin/
$./dssh
LOGTO project_name
DS_CONNECT
DS_CONNECT dsn


[T_TEST]
Driver=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded_odbc/lib/VMmsss23.so
IANAAppCodePage=113
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol driver
Database=dbname
LogonID=123
Password=133
Address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433
QuotedId=No
AnsiNPW=No
```